# Have Links inside the frame open in same window

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, frame

Have a dropdown with a bunch of links alongwith `Open directly`, `Next` and `Previous` buttons on IE8.

```
var count = -1
var total = 24

function goToNext() 
{
 count = parent.nav.openfile.file.selectedIndex
 count ++ 
 if  (count > total)
count = 0;
  parent.display.location= parent.nav.openfile.file.options[count].value
  parent.nav.openfile.file.selectedIndex = count
}

function goToPrevious() 
{
  count = parent.nav.openfile.file.selectedIndex
  count --
  if  (count < 0)
count = total;
  parent.display.location=parent.nav.openfile.file.options[count].value
  parent.nav.openfile.file.selectedIndex = count
}

function LoadFirst() 
{
 parent.display.location=parent.nav.openfile.file.options[0].value
}


function OpenDirectly() 
{
  parent.display.location = parent.nav.openfile.file.options[parent.nav.openfile.file.selectedIndex ].value
}
```

```
<FRAMESET  ROWS="45,*"> 
<FRAME 
 BORDER="1"
 FRAMEBORDER="YES"
 MARGINHEIGHT="10" 
 MARGINWIDTH="10" 
 NAME="nav" 
 SCROLLING="NO" 
 SRC="/Slide/test.jsp"
/> 
<FRAME 
  BORDER="1"
  FRAMEBORDER="YES"
  MARGINHEIGHT="10" 
  MARGINWIDTH="10" 
  NAME="display" 
  ID="display"
  SCROLLING="AUTO" 
  SRC="/page.html"
 /> 
 </FRAMESET>
```

Above is the code(test.jsp followed by the HTML code containing main frame and navigation frame - the navigation frame is navigation and all the links within it should open within the main frame) which gets called on click of these buttons to move forward, previous or load directly. The issue is that these links open in either new window or new tab but never in same window. Would highly appreciate if anyone provides any recommendations around the same.

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you're preferring old fashioned `<frame>` elements over server-side includes like `<jsp:include>`?

Comment: No specific reason other than the fact that the code was written in olden times and am tasked to have the frames open up in same window.

Comment: OK, I assume that you want to stick to the HTML `<frame>` thing. That makes it a HTML/JS problem, not a JSP problem. I edited the tags to attract the right folks.

Comment: Sure Thing! +1. Wondering if it was a jsp problem, how would one approach it?

Comment: Not with an `<frame>` and a load of JS at least. Just pure JSP/JSTL/EL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every link of navigation page, you need to add the target of the `display` frame or better add `<base target="display">` to the head section of `test.jsp`. The target decides where to open the link in.